# Match a string in a STRUCT column in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a column of type "STRUCT" in hive, basically looks like a dictionary (string, string) and I want values that contain the pattern 'XXX' when the key value is 'currency'.

I'm used to PostgreSQL where in a string I'd just use:

```
select * from table_name where column_name like '%XXX%'
```

I'm trying this but it doesn't really work. Have tried things around but nothing is working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: please show us how the table is defined. kindly run this "DESCRIBE <tablename>" and give us the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized I have to use DOT (.) notation.

So it works this way:

```
select * from table_name where column_name.key_value like '%XXX%'
```